# ng -v command doesn't give the Angular CLI details

Tags: angular-cli

When I run "ng -v", I get set of commands instead of Angular CLI logo and the version details.

[Details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E529U.png)

Comment: It's `ng v`, not `ng -v`.

Comment: This Also worked. Thank you

Comment: check this out https://stackoverflow.com/a/49292277/415078

Comment: @Kuncevič Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This,

I think it is useful for you try this command,

ng --version

Comment: Thank you. It worked. But what's the difference between --version and -v?